# NavigationView with Loading More in a List Crashes with Long Press only on iPad

Tags: ios, swiftui-list, swiftui

I am creating a list that loads data when the user reaches the bottom of the list. I can crash the app when I load more elements and long-press an element within the list. The view is wrapped in a NavigationView and a NavigationLink. When the app crashes, you get EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) with the thread 1 specialized saying "RandomAccessCollection<>.index(_:offsetBy:))". Looking into the EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION I thought it could be force unwrapping, but I don't see anywhere in the code that could cause this issue.

The issue only occurs on an iPad and happens randomly. With WWDC being yesterday, I thought this would have been fixed, so we downloaded the beta for Xcode 12, and this error still occurs.

Here is the full code:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RepositoriesListContainer(viewModel: RepositoriesViewModel())
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

enum GithubAPI {
    static let pageSize = 10
    
    static func searchRepos(query: String, page: Int) -> AnyPublisher<[Repository], Error> {
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=\(query)&sort=stars&per_page=\(Self.pageSize)&page=\(page)")!
        return URLSession.shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: url) // 1.
            .tryMap { try JSONDecoder().decode(GithubSearchResult<Repository>.self, from: $0.data).items } // 2.
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main) // 3.
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

struct GithubSearchResult<T: Codable>: Codable {
    let items: [T]
}

struct Repository: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let description: String?
    let stargazers_count: Int
}

class RepositoriesViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published private(set) var state = State()
  private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
  
  // 2.
  func fetchNextPageIfPossible() {
    guard state.canLoadNextPage else { return }
    
    GithubAPI.searchRepos(query: "swift", page: state.page)
        .sink(receiveCompletion: onReceive,
              receiveValue: onReceive)
        .store(in: &subscriptions)
  }
  
  private func onReceive(_ completion: Subscribers.Completion<Error>) {
    switch completion {
    case .finished:
        break
    case .failure:
        state.canLoadNextPage = false
    }
  }
  
  private func onReceive(_ batch: [Repository]) {
    state.repos += batch
    state.page += 1
    state.canLoadNextPage = batch.count == GithubAPI.pageSize
  }

  // 3.
  struct State {
    var repos: [Repository] = []
    var page: Int = 1
    var canLoadNextPage = true
  }
}

struct RepositoriesListContainer: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: RepositoriesViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        RepositoriesList(
          repos: viewModel.state.repos,
          isLoading: viewModel.state.canLoadNextPage,
          onScrolledAtBottom: viewModel.fetchNextPageIfPossible
        )
        .onAppear(perform: viewModel.fetchNextPageIfPossible)
    }
}

struct RepositoriesList: View {
    // 1.
    let repos: [Repository]
    let isLoading: Bool
    let onScrolledAtBottom: () -> Void // 2.
    
    var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
        List {
            reposList
            if isLoading {
                loadingIndicator
            }
        }
      }
//      .OnlyStackNavigationView()
    }
    
    private var reposList: some View {
        ForEach(repos) { repo in
            // 1.
            RepositoryRow(repo: repo).onAppear {
                // 2.
                if self.repos.last == repo {
                    self.onScrolledAtBottom()
                }
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                print("TAP")
            }
            .onLongPressGesture {
                print("LONG PRESS")
            }
        }
    }
    
     private var loadingIndicator: some View {
         Spinner(style: .medium)
             .frame(idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
     }
}

struct RepositoryRow: View {
    let repo: Repository
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail()){VStack {
            Text(repo.name).font(.title)
            Text("⭐️ \(repo.stargazers_count)")
            repo.description.map(Text.init)?.font(.body)
        }}
    }
}

struct Spinner: UIViewRepresentable {
    let style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
        let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: style)
        spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
        spinner.startAnimating()
        return spinner
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIActivityIndicatorView, context: Context) {}
}



struct LandmarkDetail: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Turtle Rock")
                    .font(.title)

                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Text("Joshua Tree National Park")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("California")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
            }
            .padding()

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```